# Flutter error: info: The imported package 'flutter' isn't a dependency of the importing package

Tags: flutter, dart

My flutter project suddenly has a new error in any files that have a stateful or stateless widget (which uses the Material or Cupertino library):

**"info: The imported package 'flutter' isn't a dependency of the importing package."**

Usually if I need to import say the material library, I can right click on a flutter widget and there is an option to import it. However, this option is no longer available, so it appears there is some error or conflict with flutter SDK.

[image]

[image]

I have ran flutter clean, upgraded flutter version to no avail, and not sure how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error shows up when you removed the flutter dependency from the `pubspec.yaml` file. Make sure you have this there:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```